# How can I center an element of an SVG file displayed in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, svg

I have an SVG file displayed inside a `UIWebView`. This SVG contains a number of `<a>` tags that indicate touchable elements. After loading the SVG file, I would like to scroll the view so that a specific element is somewhere near the center of the screen.

What I have so far is something like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [diagramView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""
        "var e = document.getElementById('myelement');"
        "var top = e.offsetTop;"
        "while (e.offsetParent) {"
        "    e = e.offsetParent;"
        "    top += e.offsetTop;"
        "}"
        "alert(top);"
        //"scrollTo(0, top);"
    ];
}
```

However, `top` ends up being 0 whenever this runs. The element `e` points to the correct `<a>` element of the SVG file (checked with an `alert(e.id)`). I can't seem to find the right combination of element attributes that gives me the actual offset.

I could hard code a suitable set of offsets, but I don't really want to.

Comment: UIWebView loads an SVG document using a URI as far as I can tell. So if you add a fragment identifier of the Id of the element you want to show does it centre the display on that element? You'd be loading http://someDrawing.svg#aId where someDrawing.svg is what you're loading and aId is the id of the element you want the display to centre on per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG

Comment: @RobertLongson: I forgot to mention that I tried that but I couldn't make the file resource load with an URL fragment on the end. Also, even if that did load, it would scroll the element to the *top* of the view, but I want the element more in the center (there are parts of the diagram I want to see below *and* above the selected element). I also tried `e.scrollIntoView()` but that didn't seem to work at all (no scrolling happened, just like the code in the question).

Comment: Hi @GregHewgill just wanted to check if the below worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Please see `getBBox`, documented at `http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox` (sorry can't post as link, SO bug)

A quick demonstration is to load https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Wikipedia_logo_(svg).svg using Chrome and run `$('#path3695').getBBox().y`

And for you specifically, just use:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [diagramView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""
        "var e = document.getElementById('myelement');"
        "var top = e.getBBox().y;"
        "alert(top);"
        "scrollTo(0, top);"
    ];
}
```